# Hiding/showing annotations

Tags: ios, mapbox

I want to hide/show annotations on a map based on filters.
My approach is currently to return nil or a RMMapLayer in

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
```

It works quite as expected but if the filters are changed when the map is visible, the changes are not reflected to the map if it is not paned or zoomed (annotations that go off screen and back in screen are correctly affected -ie hidden/shown- by the filters, but annotations not leaving the screen bounds are not affected).

Is there a way to achieve this without removing and replacing all annotations on the map each time the filters are modified ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into this pull request which was not incorporated but helps with this functionality: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/pull/113